# Assigning values based on cells in a column google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the following script to insert certain values in a column based on values in another column.

```js
 for (i = 1; i < sh.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (vA[i][21]=="SP") {sh.getRange(i+1,24,1,1).setValue('01')}
        else if (vA[i][21]=="MCD") {sh.getRange(i+1,24,1,1).setValue('02')} 
        else if (vA[i][21]=="MCR") {sh.getRange(i+1,24,1,1).setValue('03')}
        else {sh.getRange(i+1,24,1,1).setValue('99')
        };
```

Basically I want to write "01" for "SP", "02" for "MCD" and "03" for "MCR", etc...

This script works ok but the process is too time-consuming when I have a few hundred rows to process. Is there any alternative? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please provide the code related to how `vA` is retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would have liked to have more of the function so I had to guess a little but I'd suggest giving something like this a try:

```
function myfunction() {
const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();//I dont know this at all
const vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();//Im guessing on this
let oA=sh.getRange(1,24,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();//which leads to this

for (i = 1; i < sh.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if (vA[i][21]=="SP") {oA[i][0]='01'}
        else if (vA[i][21]=="MCD") {oA[i][0]='02'} 
        else if (vA[i][21]=="MCR") {oA[i][0]='03'}
        else {oA[i][0]='99'};
}
sh.getRange(1,24,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
```

If anything else is going on I can't determine

Comment: this does the trick. That made a lot of sense to use setValues one time rather than every time. Much appreciated.